# NLog Archive File keeping original file name

Tags: logging, nlog

I'm using NLog to write log file with a daily time coverage, at midnight a new log file is created and the previous one is configured to be automatically archived.

The problem is that the today filename is *Log-2019-10-18.log*.  At midnight, it is archived but the filename becomes *Log-2019-10-19.log*, while i would like to keep -18  as day part in the filename.

The NLog configuration is this one:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="tp"
        fileName="C:\Log\Log${shortdate}.log"
        archiveFileName="C:\Log\Log${shortdate}.zip"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="365"
        enableArchiveFileCompression="true">
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are mixing Dynamic- with Static-Archive-Logic which doesn't work. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="tp"
        fileName="C:\Log\Log${shortdate}.log"
        archiveFileName="C:\Log\Log{#####}.zip"
        archiveNumbering="Date"  
        archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="365"
        enableArchiveFileCompression="true">
```

Notice the `{#####}` and the options `archiveNumbering="Date"` and `archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"`

See [docs of the File target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target)